# Dual UK/Australian citizen... entry to UK with Australian passport only?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

Can I re enter into the United Kingdom on my Australian Passport (with a photocopy of my british passport) ??   I am travelling to the USA and need to leave my UK passport here to get a visa sorted out to Russia, can I get back in with out my UK Passport with out any problems?

Comment: This answer seems to cover your case: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7043/do-i-have-to-enter-the-uk-on-my-uk-passport?rq=1  Do note the warning about health care.

Comment: When you say "without any problems", do you mean "just as easily as with the real British passport", or do you mean "will be able to get through the UK border, but probably with a hefty delay"?

Comment: Definitely be prepared to spend more time at customs.  My wife got interrogated for about five minutes on why she wasn't travelling on her UK passport when passing through the Eurostar passport check.  Unfortunately she's only an Australian citizen and only has an Australian passport, which took some time to convince the customs worker of.

Comment: They will allow you to enter, but be ready to spend some time. If it is any of the London airports, be ready to spend a lot of time. If you are resident in UK, it would have been much easier. But if you are resident in Australia, it will take much longer.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike the USA, the UK does *NOT* stipulate a condition that British nationals must enter with a British passport. I.e., you can use any valid passport. The motivations behind this rule are mostly rooted in various peculiarities of the Commonwealth.

You will have a landing interview with an Immigration Officer under Paragraph 41, and if successful, you'll be admitted under Paragraph 41 (unless you specifically request to be admitted under Paragraph 18 - which is emphatically not recommended).

Because your nationality is pertinent and material, you should disclose it under Paragraph 321A(2), even if the IO does not specifically ask.

Others have noted that you can expect to spend more time in your landing interview.  You can mitigate this somewhat by demonstrating that you have a clear understanding of the rules governing your visit.  Many people do not, and they in for a proper 'grilling'.

The current rules which contain the paragraphs I cited are at https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/immigration-rules