# UK citizen entering UK on US passport

Tags: usa, uk, dual-nationality

I am travelling to the UK but my UK passport is about to expire and so would like ot enter the UK with my US passport.  How is allowed and legal?

Comment: In principle, a country should allow any citizen to enter, and some countries consider expired passport to be sufficient proof of citizenship. So you may not have a problem at all (but you should obviously check)

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [Do I have to enter the UK on my UK passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7043/do-i-have-to-enter-the-uk-on-my-uk-passport) using your UK passport is *not* mandatory. So you can certainly use your US passport if that's more convenient.

Furthermore, an *expired* British citizen passport is also enough to [enter the UK](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=GB&AR=US&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=GB&EM=US&TR=00&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C#) and should be enough for the airline.