# Travel when passport has been sent for renewal

Tags: uk, passports, australian-citizens

I'm starting to worry a little. I have dual passports UK and Australia. I recently got married and had to apply for two new ones with my new name in. My Australian one was back in three weeks but my UK one has taken three months and has still not been processed due to the backlog in the UK.

My problem is I travel to the UK then to Portugal in five weeks am I able to travel there on just my Australian passport? Please help I cannot get anyone who knows and I've been left on hold for 45 mins to uk passport office…

Comment: Will you remain in the UK for a while, or are you simply continuing on to Portugal on an ongoing flight?

Comment: I will be in uk for three weeks and Portugal for ten days

Answer (score 3):

In Portugal, being a British citizen gives you some extra rights (you can work without permit, stay there longer than 90 days, use the “EU passport” lane at the border and wouldn't need entry and exit stamps) but you can also enter easily with your Australian passport (no visa needed for a short stay) so nothing to worry about.

In the UK, since you are a citizen it's generally a good idea to show the local passport but it's not mandatory (unlike in e.g. the US) and many dual citizen do enter on their “other” passport without difficulty, see [Do I have to enter the UK on my UK passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7043/do-i-have-to-enter-the-uk-on-my-uk-passport) Here as well, Australians citizens [can visit without a visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/australia/tourism).

In both cases, not having a British passport might prevent you to use your rights as British citizen but for a short visit it should not create any problems.

Answer (score 0):

As shown by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Australian_citizens), Australian citizens can enter the Schengen area (including Portugal) and stay for up to 90 days out of any 180.