# UK resident reentering UK on NZ passport as UK passport is being renewed

Tags: visas, uk, dual-nationality, new-zealand, passport-renewals

I have to travel out of the UK using my NZ passport as my UK passport is at the UK Passport Office.

Will they only give me a tourist visa on my NZ passport?

What happens when this expires?

Or can I give them the details of my UK passport (which hasn't yet expired)?

Comment: If you're a citizen, not having a valid passport should not be a problem, do you have any other proofs of your citizenship? Also, as far as I can think, giving them your old passport details should be completely fine as well! I don't think you should be entering with you NZ passport as a tourist.

Comment: Are you a British citizen? Are you concerned about reentering the UK? Will you have a valid passport (any passport) on you at this time? Are you flying?

Comment: @AdityaSomani Entering the UK with your “other” passport as a dual citizen [is no problem](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7043/do-i-have-to-enter-the-uk-on-my-uk-passport).

Comment: Thanks, AdityaSomani and @Relaxed. It's actually my kids (17 and 15) that will be travelling (alone) but yes they are British citizen, and yes flying. They will have valid NZ passports with them, and the UK passports are still valid, only they're still with the passport office being renewed. They don't have any official ID (although the eldest has a provisional drivers license and student card!), and their birth certs are from NZ. Hopefully, Aditya, you are correct that the UK passport details will be fine in themselves.

Comment: @Relaxed I did not mean that it could be a US styled hassle, but entering as a tourist if they want to go back home can lead to some unexpected surprises which could be easily avoidable I believe.