# Dual UK citizen who also has a UK Visa

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, dual-nationality, nigerian-citizens

I am a dual citizen of the UK and Nigeria. I have surprisingly been given a UK visa before I was given a UK Passport and the visa is still valid. I now have a UK passport and a valid UK visa.

Is this a problem if I choose to enter the UK with my UK passport?

Comment: No.  If you're worried about it, though, you could always ask to have the visa cancelled.

Comment: What kind of visa is it?  Did they know you were British when they gave it to you?

Comment: i guess they did, my Nigerian passport says born in the UK and shows my date of birth. I didn't undergo any face to face interview though before i got the visa so there was no real opportunity for me to be asked the question.

Comment: Of course the fact that you were born in the UK doesn't per se mean you were a British citizen.

Comment: Having the British passport greatly simplifies your travel to the UK, Europe, USA and many other places in the world. [Learn how to use two nationalities' passports.](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52100/3221)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There shouldn't be a problem with you entering the UK on your UK passport. The issue would only arise if you tried to enter on the (now technically invalid) visa. If you think there might be a problem, go through the manual checkpoint upon arrival in the UK and ask the UKBF official to cancel the visa. If they can't do it there and then, they can probably tell you if it poses an issue and if so, how to proceed.

EDIT: I assume that what you have in your Nigerian Passport is a Visa issued before becoming a British Citizen. If it is, instead, a "Certificate of Entitlement" (not actually a visa) that proves your right of abode in the UK, then it is valid until expiry and poses no problem whatsoever to entry into the UK.

Comment: What issue would arise from entering with the visa?  I infer from the word "surprisingly" that the authorities knew the OP was British when they issued it.

Comment: If it is a visa, then it is on the basis of the OP being foreign to the UK. If it is instead, as it may be, a "certificate of entitlement", or basically sticker detailing right of abode in the UK, then it is perfectly valid in place of a passport.

Comment: Even if it's (for example) a visitor's visa, I don't think there would be much trouble if the OP used it to enter the UK.  The UK seems to have very lax requirements for its citizens to enter the country.  See, for example, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7043/do-i-have-to-enter-the-uk-on-my-uk-passport.

Comment: There are no official guidelines. I would, however avoid it, as it can be construed in a negative manner. I'm about to send off an FOI request to the Home Office to clear things up.

Comment: phoog, was surprised cos i expected them to say i should go get a british passport instead when i applied for the visa..