# Naturalized citizen of UK without a UK passport

Tags: uk-citizens

A Canadian Citizen with an Indefinite Leave to Remain in the UK, I am shortly to get naturalized as a British Citizen.  However arranging documents to get a Passport will take time.  As a British Citizen can I travel outside the country and return on my Canadian Passport.  I will have a British Citizen Certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Despite what the government says at the page linked in [the previous answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/125726/19400), you cannot be denied entry to the UK if you can show that you are a British citizen.  Since Canadian passport holders can fly to the UK without a visa, you can leave the UK and return with your Canadian passport along with proof of your UK citizenship.

See a [related answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/7071/19400) in which a Canadian who is also a British subject with right of abode reports that she answers the question about not using her UK passport by saying

> that I've lived in Canada since 1969 and that it got to be too much effort to renew my British passport. Then they let me in.

In your case, if they ask, you could say that you haven't yet had time to get the passport.

I would also note that the statement "you cannot enter the UK using your BRP or certificate of British citizenship" makes no representation about whether you can enter the UK with a certificate of British citizenship *and a valid foreign passport.*

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot use the certificate to enter the UK, once you attain citizenship (congrats).

> [**Travelling to and from the UK**](https://www.gov.uk/apply-citizenship-indefinite-leave-to-remain/after-you-get-your-certificate)
>
> Once you have a British passport you must use this to enter the UK.
>
> If you do not want a British passport you can [apply for a certificate of entitlement](https://www.gov.uk/right-of-abode/apply-for-a-certificate-of-entitlement) instead.
>
> You cannot enter the UK using your BRP or certificate of British citizenship.
>
> **After you get your certificate**
>
> You must send your biometric residence permit (BRP) back to the Home Office within 5 working days of getting your certificate of British citizenship.
>
> Cut your BRP into 4 pieces and put it in a windowless envelope.
>
> Include a note saying you’re returning your permit because you’ve become a citizen. Include your name, date of birth and the document number (found on the front of the card) in the note.
>
> ```
> Naturalisation BRP Returns 
> PO Box 195 
> Bristol 
> BS20 1BT
> ```
>
> **You’ll be fined up to £1,000 if you do not return your permit within 5 working days.**

*Note: The information found on the gov.UK site has been transposed to first respond to your query, then add the advisory regarding your biometric residence permit (BRP).*

Comment: Regardless of what the gov.uk site says, if the traveler shows up at the border with a Canadian passport and a certificate of British citzienship, the immigration officer will let him or her in.  See [Do I have to enter the UK on my UK passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/7071/19400)

Comment: @phoog Due to API, however, I strongly suspect check-in staff will receive "DO NOT BOARD". So likely only possible by land (by which I mean sea as well)

Comment: @Coke why would a traveler with a valid Canadian passport receive a "do not board" indication for a flight to the UK?

Comment: @phoog Because by law (quoted in the answer), just like in the US, British citizens are supposed to enter on a British passport. While the US cannot refuse entry, airlines are not to let dual citizens onboard without a US passport (as I was told by a Checkport station manager here in Zurich). A while ago there was a couple, both originally British but one holding a German ID card and the other one a US passport. They wouldn't board the US passport holder at the gate, saying the system "wouldn't let them". Though I never asked, I suspect it was because of this.

Comment: @Coke how does.the system know that the traveler is a British citizen?

Comment: @phoog The only way I can think of is by matching the API data.