# Travel within EU as UK/USA dual citizen

Tags: usa, uk, spain

I need to travel from Spain to UK and return on my US passport. Is there a reason I cannot do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7043/do-i-have-to-enter-the-uk-on-my-uk-passport What is your immigration status in Spain?

Comment: Those examples might answer my question, although I'm not sure since there are three countries involved. @Traveller I have indefinite leave to remain in Spain.

Comment: What kind of UK passport do you have? Are you a British citizen? If so, why do you need to travel on a US passport?

Comment: Don't you have your TIE?

Comment: I don't see any reason why you couldn't do that. It seems strange, sure, as I would have thought that the entry process would be quicker with your British passport. Do you have some need to get a stamp in your US passport?

Comment: I need to renew my UK passport, and I would like to use my US passport in the meantime. I am a British citizen. I do not yet have my TIE, but I have until the end of this year to obtain it.

Comment: You'll enter Spain as a US citizen fine, also coming back to the UK you don't legally need to use a British passport, do you have any other proof of citizenship? I think it would help to talk to an immigration officer and enter as a UK citizen even with your US passport to stop complications. But at the end of the day you're not going to get deported for overstaying in the UK as you're a British citizen.

Comment: @TooTea yes, thanks. The consensus seems to be that it should not be a problem and that any supporting information regarding my UK citizenship and details of my trip should be provided to the border guard upon entry.